# No questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, new-nav

So this happened to me earlier today, a refresh of the page cleared the issue and I haven't been able to reproduce since. I thought I'd share here maybe someone else has seen this.

In the screenshot you can see I am on "*filter: all tags show: all sort: newest*".

The question count is also missing from the top right.

[image: No Questions complete with hand drawn circles].

For reference the url in the browser was: https://stackoverflow.com/?tagFilter=all

Comment: I think I have run into this too.  But like you said, it resolved itself upon taking any action.  I changed my sorting to active, but same thing.  Now that you have a screenshot as proof, I'm more convinced that occurrence wasn't my fault (like just return 0 filter results).

Comment: This is a known issue where the query takes longer than the page rendering is willing to wait. Reload the page and if the query has finished in the meantime you'll get your results.

Comment: It has actually just happened again, are the Stack Overflow servers under pressure at the moment?

Comment: This happened to me once but I hope everyone isn't missing the funny reference to battleship. Kudos to the SE team for keeping things fun! Yes, I'm easily amused