# Tag pages and review pages not loading properly

Tags: bug, tags, review-queues

Is it just me or are the individual tag pages and review pages taking a long time to load, and then failing to load altogether?

These don't work: 
[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) 
[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

And this doesn't work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/review

But this does work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/

I'm getting the good old "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

Strangely if I log out and try to go to a tag page it loads instantly... 
Log back in, try again, and after a long wait "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

It is on both Firefox and Chrome on Windows 8.

Comment: I can reproduce this - Linux, Chrome 44 Beta.

Comment: @Makoto did you try logging out as well?

Comment: No; I actually do see the tag pages show up if I'm not in a session (incognito).  Perhaps it has to do with the new tag search?  Are you using that?  (I am and am able to see similar behavior to you.)

Comment: No, even the links in the question above aren't working for me. Just noticed the log out oddity when I was checking other browsers.

Comment: @StevenPenny Hmm that's not good...

Comment: @StevenPenny: I got forcibly logged out (while reviewing) for the first time in ... months, I think. No errors, just suddenly a loaded page stopped recognizing me as logged in.

Comment: @StevenPenny try: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/

Comment: Where's a team member when you need one... Well looks like its time to [spin the wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: Searching doesn't appear to be working for me either

Comment: @durron597 searching for tags or searching in general?

Comment: I searched for a query that involved a tag but had other things too

Comment: @durron597 It looks like I can search specific words but not tags, "css" works, while "[css]" doesn't

Comment: internal server error 500

Comment: Links to review queues so you can still do some reviewwws, yay!

[low qual](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)
[close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close)
[reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen)
[edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)
[first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts)
[triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage)
[late answ](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers)

Comment: Can reproduce on Firefox, Opera, and Chrome latest on Windows 7. Only popular tags seem to be affected. I can load tags that only have like 300 or 6000 questions. But tags like [tag:css] and [tag:javascript] are not loading.

Comment: Same error i can also reproduce on firefox windows 7. And message like: *"It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault."*

Answer (score 27):

No idea what's going on here. Presumably /review just hates Freedom.

I turned switches and flipped knobs randomly until it started loading.

I'm reluctant to call it fixed though.

Comment: All the things that weren't working before are working for me now.

Comment: @pnuts That account is run from SRE perspective, so they focus on events like "site is down" rather than "a particular page times out". Also, they tend to tweet about _planned_ interruptions  to inform users in advance. Finally, Nick Craver was on vacation through today, and the majority of tweets there are his.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that everyone was out grilling hotdogs, @pnuts. The only reason I noticed was that someone pinged me in chat about an unrelated issue. Blame the British.

Comment: @Shog9 seems to me like SO severs are under pressure, I keep getting the "thats a miss" a lot at the moment. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/no-questions-on-stack-overflow