# Where is the link for review gone for selected tag?

Tags: support, review-queues, new-nav

Title says it all, I used to click on a tag, e.g.: `R` then in tag description window it would show X number in an orange box that needs reviewing, when clicked I could only review posts that have `R` tag.

I can't see it any more, see screenshot:
[image]

This feature is described at [Easy close review queue filtering interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface/231856#231856)

Comment: I couldn't find where that feature was described or announced but I finally found it on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/158100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This goes back to [an issue we had over the July 4th holiday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298541/tag-pages-and-review-pages-not-loading-properly/298546#298546): calculating these numbers was slowing the loading of tag pages to crawl.

Since this was affecting users of the largest tags on the site and no one was around to determine the source of the problem, I responded by just turning it off. They'll remain off until someone has time to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Did the underlying problem since then became bigger or smaller? If smaller, is there a chance you're going to give this a try again, as in turning the feature back on?