# Can we have links to tag-filtered review queues on tag pages or the 10k tools page?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues, 10k-tools

Currently I'm focusing on a few tags, and it would be great if I could get an option to filter privilege tools for specific tags, either in [Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) or an option in the tag's header section: [image: Like this].

There I could access close-votes, suggested edits, etc. for that specific tag:

Expected advantages:

- Can reduce the number of close votes: Personally I can contribute more effectively and accurately in review. Currently, if I go there in Review I will get posts in different tags, so I will hit `Skip`. After a few hits I stop reviewing and go back to my job. If the review queue were more specific, then it would be more effective.

Comment: Since you're saying you need to hit skip for reviews with different tags, you might not be aware, but you can *already* filter reviews by tag. Click the 'filter' text just next to the name of the review: https://i.imgur.com/IpR91T4.png

Comment: There was once a link there for accessing the close vote queue, with the number of posts in the queue but it performance was so terrible that it had to be turned off.

Comment: Couldn't find it on MSO because it still sat on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/158100 and here is the report that it was disabled: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299902/where-is-the-link-for-review-gone-for-selected-tag.  I annoyed Shog9 on his answer to revisit that close vote review queue access thingy ....

Comment: @Rob: That option is there, but I haven't noticed/used that before that's why come up with this question. It will be more suitable if it is added to the specific tag section

Comment: Yea, we could use some more buttons / links there... There aren't enough yet.

Comment: @Rob is there a technical reason that the filter is limited to three tags? Could this be increased?

Comment: I agree this would be a neat feature to have, but not for the reasons you specify (as Rob explains in his comment above)

Comment: related: [The 10k tools could do with some love](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345134/the-10k-tools-could-do-with-some-love)

Comment: @Turnip I'm not sure, sorry - your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Turnip I believe they had put in the limit due to performance issues. I vaguely remember reading an answer about this from Shog9 on MSE. Though I can't find it right now.